# When using Dyntopo, is there a way to adjust how far each vertex is pushed or pulled?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I am using dyntopo, and when I try to shape a square down into another shape that I want (torso, arm, etc.) it pushes some vertices too far down. Can I adjust that somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to adjust the *strength* of the brush you are currently using.

You can also adjust the *detail size* with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> 
(This will display as a percentage or as a pixel count depending on the *detail type* being used.) The [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html) has an  explanation of each one.

Changing the *radius* of the brush with <kbd>F</kbd> as needed is also useful.